# Вывод массива через for с разными индексами

Tags: php, html

Всем добрый день.
Изучаю пхп.Столкнулся с такой проблемой,как вывод массива через цикл for,с разными индексами(ключами)
Сам код

```
$f_a = ["int1"=>1,"int2"=>2,"int3"=>3,4,5,6,7];
for($i = 0; $i < count($f_a);$i++){
    if(isset($f_a[$i]))
        echo $f_a[$i];
    elseif(isset($f_a["int".$i]))
        echo $f_a["int".$i];
}
```

На экран выводить

> 4567

То бишь элементы со стандартным индексом
В чем может быть проблема,никак не могу понять..
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для перебора ассоциативных (в которых ключи не только числа) массивов используется [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$f_a = ["int1"=>1,"int2"=>2,"int3"=>3,4,5,6,7];
foreach ($f_a as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.'<br>';
}
```